# Importing data form SQL Server to Power BI - Can I M code from Power Query into WHERE clause of sql code

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-synapse

I am wondering is it possible to include the M code of Power Query in Power BI in the WHERE clause of a SQL statement, when I am getting data from Azure Synapse Analytics SQL to Power BI?

The table I am querying is in Azure Synapse Analytics and it is more than 1 million rows.
So I am trying to import only the rows for specific Post codes.
The problem is that these Post codes are being provided via separate Excel file which is uploaded to Power BI.

I have used the M code from the comments, but tweaked it a bit in order to put get a coma between each postcode.

```
= Text.Combine(MyTable[PostCode2], ",")
```

Then I want to use this code, which returns:

```
'CO16 0AS','CO10 8JR','CO1 2TA','NE15 8TN'
```

I want to use this in the WHERE clause in the SQL statement which I write when I "Get Data" from "Azure Synapse Analytics SQL":
[image]

This is the code:
[image]

And I am getting the following error:
[image]

I have tried remove the #, the " symbols, brackets, and other variations, but nothing works.

Comment: Powerquery (Excel) result to PowerQuery (SQL), yes. DAX measure to PowerQuery, no. Do you really mean a Measure?

Comment: Hi, yes, I really mean a power bi calculated measure, if it is possible

Comment: No, not possible. Importing from SQL happens once at dataset refresh, after that DAX kicks in for any Calculated Tables & Columns. Then once the dataset refresh is done, and only during report viewing do the measures kick in. What's the intention? User can select multiple postcodes, and then pull these in? If so, you will need to look at DirectQuery to SQL with [Dynamic M query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters).

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining. I will receive a file with specific post codes each week, but this file is shared via an email in excel format. The I want to get a Local Authority name for the "NamePostcode" table using the post codes provided in the excel file. Since the "NamePostcode" table is huge I don't want to import in Power BI fully, but only return result for the post codes I am checking, which I doubt will ever be more than 20. I will read through the link you have posted

Comment: You will be loading the Excel file into PowerQuery, if from here you are able to select which post codes you want (in PowerQuery), then you can use that in your SQL.

Comment: That sounds like it should work for what I need. Are you able to give me more details on how to do this exactly?  I can take only the post codes from the file in power query and delete all other columns, but then how can I reference this "step/table/column" in the SQL script? Is this something I can do with the Dynamic M queries you have posted as an article? I haven't had a chance to read it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a Query in PowerQuery of a table with a column of the Post Codes you are after. You would generate the string for SQL `IN` with the following:

```
"'" & Text.Combine(#"Post Codes"[Post Code], "','") & "'"
```

Where `#"Post Codes"` is the name of the query, and `[Post Code]` is the column name.

Add the above in the Advanced Editor of your SQL import, and watch out for `"`. For example:

```
... "SELECT * ... FROM ... WHERE ... IN ('" & Text.Combine(#"Post Codes"[Post Code], "','") & "')"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I changed the M code a bit to put each post code in a single quotes. This returns exactly what I would write in the SQL query.M code is --> = Text.Combine(MyTable[PostCode2], ",")  , and it returns  -->   'CO16 0AS','CO10 8JR','CO1 2TA','NE15 8TN'.   Then I have tried adding this into the SQL script when I connect via Power Query, but it is still not working, I am getting different errors depending on each change I do to the code, because I have tried many variations:  SELECT LAName, Postcode
FROM myDb.LAToPostcode
WHERE Postcode = ( Text.Combine(#"MyTable"[PostCode2]))

Comment: Update your question with the full PowerQuery of your query (copy'n'paste from Advanced Editor).

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post and pasted some screen shots, hopefully they will help

Comment: For now just add `IN ('something')` to the SQL so it loads. Then you'll see your query, then you can click on Advanced Edit to add the code in the answer in place. You'll know it when you see it - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yhf5.png

Comment: Hi, yes, it worked now, when I pasted the code from your answer to Advance editor. At first it kicked another error Formula.Firewall...., but when I changed Privacy settings it worked. Thank you for sticking with me !